# How to handle batch SQL inserts from Spring JDBC when table column too small

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, insert, spring-batch

I'm trying to batch insert a large volume of data into a MYSQL database and need advice about how to handle the situation where a table column is not large enough to cope with the size of the incoming data.

Since the data set is very large (over 1Gb) I'm performing a streaming read of the input data into memory. At certain points, I "flush" the data and try to insert it into the table using jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate . All of the columns of the destination table are VARCHARs and are assumed to be of size 50. This is perfectly adequate for the vast majority of the data. However since occasionally data arrives which is larger than size 15, the INSERT will fail (Data too long for column).

What is the best approach to tackling this issue? I don't want to blindly make all of the table columns larger since this seems like a strategy which won't scale very well. I'd also prefer not to pre-parse the data due to its size. So should I wait for the fail, then perform an appropriate "ALTER TABLE" and re-submit the data? Is it possible to cache away the failed items, determine the required column size and re-submit failed items only?

I'm looking for pointers and general advice about the optimal way to perform this.

Thanks.

Comment: **Garbage In / Garbage Out :** the only way to to test the data and truncate it before trying to do the insert. Dynamically `ALTER TABLE` statements is just a huge mistake. What happens when one column is accidentally 10,000 characters long? And it might just be me, but 1GB of data isn't _large_ anymore.

Comment: Did you accept any of the proposed answers or did you come up with and alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet is validating data before putting it into the insert batch. That way you can either reject object with too long strings or truncate strings to the required size.

Comment: Like I said I really don't want to validate unless absolutely necessary due to the size of the incoming data.

Comment: @Phil: That's what we do with Oracle. If I understand the following link correctly, MySQL can be configured to truncate excessively long strings on insert: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018954/php-pdo-mysql-how-to-automatically-clip-strings-to-the-proper-length-on-insert

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that you're using MySQL and varchar columns.  It isn't clear to me if the current column width is 15 or 50, but in either case there is no performance penalty to making the column definitions varchar(255).  I assume that would allow many of the failure cases to succeed.

You didn't indicate whether the requirement is that all data must end up in the database unaltered, or if you can truncate or modify the data to allow it to fit.  Assuming you can alter the data, here are a couple of additional thoughts:

For handling data that is still too long, I like Olaf's suggestion of validating the data before including in the batch.  I would validate each record as it is read and then decide whether to add it to the insert batch or process it as a failure (store in file?).

Also, you don't really indicate how much processing you're doing on the data after reading and before insering in the database.  If you aren't doing any, then perhaps you should look into bulk loading tools available for MySQL (I'm not familiar enough to tell you).  Typically these tools are able to handle these types of cases for you.