# Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column

```
CREATE  TABLE `TEST` 
(

  `idTEST` INT NOT NULL ,

  `TESTcol` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`idTEST`) 
);
```

Now `Insert` some values

```
INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES
(
    1,
    'Vikas'
)

select 

SELECT * FROM TEST;
```

Inserting record more than the `length`

```
INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES
(
    2,
    'Vikas Kumar Gupta Kratika Shukla Kritika Shukla'
)
```

If we `select` the `length`

```
SELECT LENGTH('Vikas Kumar Gupta Kratika Shukla Kritika Shukla')

 '47'
```

And it is showing the error message

**Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column**

But what is my expectation is, I want to insert at least first 45 characters in Table

please let me know if the question is not clear.

I know the cause of this error. I am trying to insert values more than the length of datatype.

I want solution in MySQL as It is possible in `MS SQL`. So I hope it would also be in **MySQL**.

Comment: so what you want to have done is that if the value is longer then 45 characters you only want to insert the first 45?

Comment: See this post for info on how to have mysql truncate fields:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018954/automatically-clip-strings-to-the-proper-length-on-insert

Comment: You can use: SELECT CAST(('Vikas Kumar Gupta Kratika Shukla Kritika Shukla') AS CHAR)

Comment: Make sure you don't have trigger on your table

Answer (score 80, accepted):

MySQL will truncate any insert value that exceeds the specified column width.

to make this without error try switch your `SQL mode` to not use `STRICT`.

[Mysql reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html)

---

### EDIT:

To change the mode

This can be done in two ways:

1. Open your `my.ini` (Windows) or `my.cnf` (Unix) file within the MySQL installation directory, and look for the text "sql-mode".

Find:

Code:

```
# Set the SQL mode to strict 
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Replace with:

Code:

```
# Set the SQL mode to strict 
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Or

2. You can run an SQL query within your database management tool, such as phpMyAdmin:

Code:

```
SET @@global.sql_mode= '';
```

Comment: How I could change the mode]

Comment: you restarted your apache server ?

Comment: Thank you, this solution work very well for me. 

SET @@global.sql_mode= 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

Comment: >> SET @@global.sql_mode= 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';It didn't work for me!

Comment: `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` means _If a value could not be inserted as given into a transactional table, abort the statement. For a nontransactional table, abort the statement if the value occurs in a single-row statement or the first row of a multiple-row statement._ [as per docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-important) | [Read More](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)

Comment: use this query to check the current sql mode `select @@global.sql_mode from dual`

Comment: Is it a good practice to disable strict mode, and does truncate remove a part of the string if exceeded ?

Answer (score 3):

Besides the answer given above, I just want to add that this error can also occur while importing data with incorrect lines terminated character.

For example I save the dump file in csv format in windows. then while importing

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path_to_csv_folder/db.csv' INTO TABLE table1
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 ENCLOSED BY '"'
 ESCAPED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Windows saved end of line as \r\n (i.e. CF LF) where as I was using \n. I was getting crazy why phpMyAdmin was able to import the file while I couldn't. Only when I open the file in notepadd++ and saw the end of file then I realized that mysql was unable to find any lines terminated symbol (and I guess it consider all the lines as input to the field; making it complain.)

Anyway after making from \n to \r\n; it work like a charm.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path_to_csv_folder/db.csv' INTO TABLE table1
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 ENCLOSED BY '"'
 ESCAPED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that switching off the STRICT mode is not a good option because the app can start losing the data entered by users.

If you receive values for the TESTcol from an app you could add model validation, like in Rails

```rb
validates :TESTcol, length: { maximum: 45 }
```

If you manipulate with values in SQL script you could truncate the string with the [SUBSTRING](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php) command

```
INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES
(
    1,
    SUBSTRING('Vikas Kumar Gupta Kratika Shukla Kritika Shukla', 0, 45)
);
```

Comment: SUBSTRING should start at Position 1

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me recently.
I was fully migrate to MySQL 5.7, and everything is in default configuration.

All previously answers are already clear and I just want to add something.

This 1406 error could happen in your function / procedure too and not only to your table's column length.

In my case, I've trigger which call procedure with IN parameter varchar(16) but received 32 length value.

I hope this help someone with similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a step I use with ubuntu. It will allow you to insert more than 45 characters from your input but MySQL will cut your text to 45 characters to insert into the database.

1. Run command

   > sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
2. Then paste this code

   > [mysqld]
   >   sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
3. restart MySQL

   > sudo service mysql restart;

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is prioritized on search-results, I will quickly say that you can **pre-truncate** your data before saving using **substr()**; then move on to the more serious issue of saving large data resulting in **Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column**.

I disagree with all answers and comments advising on **turning off** the strict mode. The presumption is, data that needs saving must be saved - not left to the chance of mysteriously disappearing at will without notice. Good table structure is advised but if you must save any **large** data, you can change the column's capacity to:

```
TEXT: 65,535 characters - 64 KB
MEDIUMTEXT: 16,777,215 - 16 MB
LONGTEXT: 4,294,967,295 characters - 4 GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the limits of your SQL database. Maybe you'r exceeding the field limit for this row.

Comment: Why so many downwotes, I've had varchar(10000) and trying to give 10254 characters and this error occured. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while using the imagefield in Django.
 `post_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='home2/khamulat/mydomain.com/static/assets/images/uploads/blog/%Y/%m/%d', height_field=None, default=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)`

I just removed the excess code as shown above to  `post_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/uploads/blog/%Y/%m/%d', height_field=None, default=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)`  and the error was gone

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after creating my table structure first with a primary key set then trying to upload a csv file. My CSV file had information in the primary key column. It was an export from another sql server. No matter how I tried to export and import, it wouldn't work.

What I did to solve it was to drop my primary key column in my db and my csv, upload, then add my primary key column back.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers above indicate to update my.ini file, but I feel it would be better to alter column lengeth to TEXT or LONGTEXT, so that any higher length can be added.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem when I am trying to save 0 in a Boolean type column but mistakenly I was passing 0 as an string.

Make sure you will pass the correct data with satisfying datatype.

**In my case I was trying to save '0' instead of 0 in a Boolean type column.**

Answer (score -2):

Go to your Models and check, because you might have truncated a number of words for that particular column eg. max_length="150".