# Using source command corrupts non Unicode text encoding

Tags: mysql, windows

I have to import some data containing national characters not coded as Unicode into stand alone **MySQL Version: 5.0.18 running on Windows7 64bit**. After some initial problems I finally got it working in **MySQL** console.

But as the data is more than 50 MByte typing into console and or using clipboard is not possible. So I created script file only to find out that the national characters are gibberish after import.

The problem is that if I use `source` command with any file the encoding broke. If I open the same file and copy the stuff to console by clipboard all works as should. Here smallest **MCVE** to test this:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbs;
CREATE DATABASE dbs;
USE dbs;

SET NAMES latin2;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tab`;
CREATE TABLE `tab` (`ix` INT default 0,`nam` VARCHAR(50) default '' );
INSERT INTO `tab` VALUES
 (1,'aacdeillnoorrstuuyzAACDEILLNOORRSTUUYZ'),
 (2,'áäčďéíĺľňóôŕřšťú ýžÁ ČĎÉÍĹĽŇÓ ŔŘŠŤÚ ÝŽ');
SELECT * FROM `tab`;
```

When I copy this to **MySQL** console by **clipboard** the output is like this:

```
+------+----------------------------------------+
| ix   | nam                                    |
+------+----------------------------------------+
|    1 | aacdeillnoorrstuuyzAACDEILLNOORRSTUUYZ |
|    2 | áäčďéíĺľňóôŕřšťú ýžÁ ČĎÉÍĹĽŇÓ ŔŘŠŤÚ ÝŽ |
+------+----------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which is desired. But when I put all this into `test.sql` file and run

```
source test.sql;
```

I got this output:

```
+------+----------------------------------------+
| ix   | nam                                    |
+------+----------------------------------------+
|    1 | aacdeillnoorrstuuyzAACDEILLNOORRSTUUYZ |
|    2 | ßńŔ´ÚÝňż˛ˇ˘Ó°ÜŁ˙ ř×┴ ╚¤╔═┼╝ĎË └ěŐŹ┌ ŢÄ |
+------+----------------------------------------+
```

Which is obviously wrong (looks like some default **MS-DOS** charset). I think the problem is not on side of table nor database as this is the same for pure text outs like:

```
SET NAMES latin2;
SELECT 'áäčďéíĺľňóôŕřšťú ýžÁ ČĎÉÍĹĽŇÓ ŔŘŠŤÚ ÝŽ' AS 'aacdeillnoorrstuuyzAACDEILLNOORRSTUUYZ';
```

Which outputs with clipboard:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| aacdeillnoorrstuuyzAACDEILLNOORRSTUUYZ |
+----------------------------------------+
| áäčďéíĺľňóôŕřšťú ýžÁ ČĎÉÍĹĽŇÓ ŔŘŠŤÚ ÝŽ |
+----------------------------------------+
```

And with `source` file:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| aacdeillnoorrstuuyzAACDEILLNOORRSTUUYZ |
+----------------------------------------+
| ßńŔ´ÚÝňż˛ˇ˘Ó°ÜŁ˙ ř×┴ ╚¤╔═┼╝ĎË └ěŐŹ┌ ŢÄ |
+----------------------------------------+
```

It is like when importing from files the encoding got screwed. Or while inputing to **MySQL** console through **Keyboard** or **Clipboard** the coding got changed.

So what is going on and how to correct this (without the loss of data)?

- using `<` command line option instead of `source` does not help
- using `-e` command line option for `source` does not help
- using default charset command line option does not help
- using **UTF8** for non Unicode string lead to [Data too long errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46727013/2521214) and loss of data
- data in clipboard is the same as in the file

**[Edit1]**

Well I tried newer version of **MySQL 5.7.19** which took mi quite a while to get started as they change the initialization and things (wtf? that insanity got 1.8 GByte without any data !).  It behaves the same no matter what I do. So I tried to use **UTF8** encoding:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbs;
CREATE DATABASE dbs CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';
USE dbs;

SET NAMES utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tab`;
CREATE TABLE `tab` (`ix` INT default 0,`nam` VARCHAR(50) default '' ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';
INSERT INTO `tab` VALUES
 (1,'áäčďéíĺľňóôŕřšťú ýžÁ ČĎÉÍĹĽŇÓ ŔŘŠŤÚ ÝŽ'),
 (2,'aacdeillnoorrstuuyzAACDEILLNOORRSTUUYZ');
SELECT * FROM `tab`;

#SELECT 'áäčďéíĺľňóôŕřšťú ýžÁ ČĎÉÍĹĽŇÓ ŔŘŠŤÚ ÝŽ' AS 'aacdeillnoorrstuuyzAACDEILLNOORRSTUUYZ';

#SHOW COLLATION;
#SHOW CHARACTER SET;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
```

And Yes the script file is converted to **UTF8**.  Now here is my.ini setting:

```
[mysql]

 default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]

 skip-character-set-client-handshake
 character-set-server=utf8
 collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
```

This **finally worked** for the file using `source` here the result:

```
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ix   | nam                                                                      |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | áäčďéíĺľňóôŕřšťú ýžÁ ČĎÉÍĹĽŇÓ ŔŘŠŤÚ ÝŽ                                   |
|    2 | aacdeillnoorrstuuyzAACDEILLNOORRSTUUYZ                                   |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                              |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                               |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                               |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                               |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                             |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                               |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                               |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                               |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do MySQL and the script agree on a character encoding? Looks like the database is interpreting the script file using a different character encoding than it is saved in.

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah .. but how to change it or force it to do what it should ? The only charset that pass all the entries is latin2 which is consistent with the data source but passing through file breaks it ... like something re-encode it into different charset possibly on Windows side...

Comment: Try to save the script file using UTF-8 with a BOM. You can use Notepad to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify a `CHARACTER SET` when creating the table, preferably on the column itself.  Otherwise, you get some default from `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

`SET NAMES` establishes the encoding in the client.

When `INSERTing` or `SELECTing`, the encoding is changed from the client's encoding (`SET NAMES`) to the column's (`... VARCHAR ... CHARACTER SET ...`).

Do you really need latin2?  The world is moving to UTF-8.

Comment: I added edit1 with UTF8 solution. The latin2 did not work no matter what I did. I wanted to use UTF8 in the first place but I was unable to get it to work with the Old MySQL version (even if it should work but the my.ini settings was ignored somehow). I upgraded to `5.7.19` and UTF8 stuff finally works (latin2 still not however) so I consider this as solved. As the query in your answer lead me to solution I Accept your answer.

Comment: Yeah it is a challenge.  As pointed out in "Best practice" of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored , there are 6 places where you need to specify the character set.  Else things break in about 5 different ways.