# How can I fill all bits of a bit datatype equal to 1?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE users SET active = -1 WHERE id = ? AND active IS NULL
```

It works on my current MySQL version. I mean it sets `1111111111` as `active` value. Noted that `active` is `BIT(10)` datatype.

But recently I've upgraded the MySQL version and it throws:

> string(94) "SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'active' at row 1"

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Try change datatype from bit(10) to just BIT.

Comment: @BlackMarker What about `UPDATE users SET active = b'1111111111' WHERE id = ? AND active IS NULL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ERROR 1406: 1406: Data too long for column" but it shouldn't be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418870/error-1406-1406-data-too-long-for-column-but-it-shouldnt-be)

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34419094/2055998) answer.

Comment: Try if it works with `bit(32)` or `bit(64)`.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  There was a change in the definition of `BIT` sometime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something with a bunch of bits, use `BINARY(2)` to get 16 bits.  If you need a really long bit string, use `BLOB` or `MEDIUMBLOB`.