# What data type to set?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I am getting the following error even though I have set datatype as "longtext" for column "text" -

> 03:28:07 org.apache.commons.logging.Log$error$5 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'text' at row 2

What are the other possible data types? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your text is too long for `longtext` ?

Comment: yes i guess that's what the error is saying. Please read the error carefully.

Comment: you could try switching sql mode. [go through this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949038/error-code-1406-data-too-long-for-column-mysql)

Comment: I'd like to see the Java code which caused this error, and a sample/description of the data involved.

Answer (score 0):

If `LONGTEXT` format is not enough for you, you can use the `BLOB` format, the MySQL Documentation got an article about this problem. [The BLOB and TEXT Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)