# Django equivalent for MySQL bit datatype

Tags: mysql, django, boolean

I am facing issues with "makeflag" field which is bit(1) type in my database(MySQL). I have tried using booleanField and bit1booleanfield with below syntax. But i am getting error with both. when i try POST request with json data on this model,

I get error as

> "Data too long for column" on passing 1 or 0 as value.

And when i give true or false as value, then i get **400 Bad Request**. 
Can someone please help me understand how can i post data using django and json for bit field (of mysql).

```
makeflag=models.BooleanField(db_column='MakeFlag', default=1)

makeflag=Bit1BooleanField()
```

*My model is the next:*

```
class Product(models.Model):
    productid = models.AutoField(db_column='ProductID', primary_key=True)  
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=50)  
    productnumber = models.CharField(db_column='ProductNumber', max_length=25)  
    makeflag = models.TextField(db_column='MakeFlag', max_length=1)
    color = models.CharField(db_column='Color', max_length=15, blank=True)
    safetystocklevel = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='SafetyStockLevel')  
    reorderpoint = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='ReorderPoint')  
    standardcost = models.FloatField(db_column='StandardCost')
```

Comment: Please could add more info related to error that you got ? And how are you posting the data with JSON?

Comment: Hi,
My sample json is as below
{
"name": "ramram",
"productnumber":"1",
"makeflag":1,
"color":"Blue",
"safetystocklevel":"1000",
"reorderpoint":"750",
"standardcost":"0"}

Comment: Why you send a string like `"1000", "750", "0"` to the safetystocklevel, reorderpoint and standardcost SmallIntegerFields. These fields must be integers no strings...

Comment: i am posting data using postman

Comment: Error  :
File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py" in execute   raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py" in cmd_query sqlstate=exc.sqlstate
During handling of the above exception (Data too long for column 'MakeFlag' at row 1), another exception occurred:

File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py" in statement
 return self._executed.strip().decode('utf8')
During handling of the above exception ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'), another exception occurred:

Comment: Could you take a print of your SQL schema in order to see what is happening at MySQL level. You only have to do the next command: `desc product;` on the MySQL client console

Comment: ProductID int(11)
Name varchar(50)
ProductNumber varchar(25)
MakeFlag bit(1)
Color varchar(15)
SafetyStockLevel smallint(6)
ReorderPoint smallint(6)
StandardCost double

Comment: It worked with quotes when inserted manually using mysql workbench.Hence trying same with json

Comment: Maybe, do want to take a look what SQL query Django is creating... You could do this with some plugins but the fastest way is this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running

Comment: For the other hand, could be problem of MySQL engine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949038/error-code-1406-data-too-long-for-column-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use [django-mysql](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-mysql) for mysql specific functionality. Have a look docs for bit [here](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/null_bit1_boolean_fields.html)