# MariaDB: SELECT INSERT from ODBC CONNECT engine from SQL Server keeps causing "error code 1406 data too long"

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-connect-engine

**Objective**: Using MariaDB I want to read some data from MS SQL Server (via ODBC Connect engine) and SELECT INSERT it into a local table.

**Issue**: I keep geting "error code 1406 data too long" even if source and destination varchar fields have the very same size (see further details)

**Details**:
The query which I'm trying to execute is in the form:

```
INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE(NUMERO_DOCUMENTO)
SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(NUMERO_DOCUMENTO),0,5)
FROM CONNECT_SRC_TABLE
```

The above is the very minimal subset of fields which causes the problem.

- The source CONNECT Table is actually a view inside SQL Server. The destination table has been defined so to be identical to the the ODBC CONNECT Table (same field names, same NULL constranints, same filed types ans sizes)
- There's no issue on a couple of other VARCHAR fields
- The issue is happening with a filed `NUMERO_DOCUMENTO VARCHAR(14) DEFAULT NULL` where the max length from the input table is 14
- The same issue is also happening with 2 other fields ont the same table

All in all it seems to be an issue with the source data rather then the destination table.

**Attemped workarounds**:

- I tried to force silent truncation but, reasonably, this does not make any difference: [Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949038/error-code-1406-data-too-long-for-column-mysql)
- I tried enlarging the destination field with no appreciable effect `NUMERO_DOCUMENTO VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL`
- I tried to TRIM the source field (hidden spaces?) and to limit its size at source to no avail: `INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE(NUMERO_DOCUMENTO) SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(NUMERO_DOCUMENTO),0,5) FROM CONNECT_SRC_TABLE` but the very same error is always returned

**Workaround**:
 I tried performing the same thing using a `FOR x IN (src_query) DO INSERT .... END FOR` and this solution seems to work: this means that the problem is not into the data itself but in how the engine performs the INSERT SELECT query

Comment: Is there a typo in the code example?  `SUBST` => `SUBSTR`?

Comment: yep, thansk for pointing out!