# Data Too Long for Column - Spring-Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using Hibernate in my Spring application. I'm inserting the Nft object into my database. But after when i changed the "sellStatus" column to "false" or "1" it says "Data too long for column" .

Heres my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nft")
@Data
public class Nft {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String qtype;

    private int serial;

    private Long cost;

    private boolean sellStatus;
```

And this is the error :

```
ERROR 1406: 1406: Data too long for column 'sell_status' at row 1
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `nftbazaar`.`nft` SET `sell_status` = '1' WHERE (`id` = '1')
```

Comment: Hope this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949038/error-code-1406-data-too-long-for-column-mysql

Comment: Can you add the table schema? Thanks

Comment: boolean store `True` or `False` for `0` or `1` you want to change datatype as `private String sellStatus;` or `private Integer sellStatus`

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql from:

```
UPDATE `nftbazaar`.`nft` SET `sell_status` = '1' WHERE (`id` = '1')
```

To:

```
UPDATE `nftbazaar`.`nft` SET `sell_status` = true WHERE (`id` = '1')
```

OR

```
UPDATE `nftbazaar`.`nft` SET `sell_status` = false WHERE (`id` = '1')
```

Depending on your need to deal with true or false for boolean. Let the database handle your true or false to 0 or 1.